# How to transform a nested json into a data frame in r?

Tags: json, r, list, dataframe

I am using a third party response in json and I want to analyse it using r. To do so I need to transform the json into an r data frame. For instance my json might look like this:

```
{
    "useless_info1": "trash1",
    "useless_info2": "trash2",
    "useless_info3": "trash3",
    "usefull_info": [
        {
            "color": "red",
            "sizes": [
                "height": 128,
                "width": 40
            ],
            "flavour": "bitter"
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "sizes": [
                "height": 30,
                "width": 10
            ],
            "flavour": "sweet"
        },
    ]
}
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
color     sizes_height     sizes_width    flavor
--------  ---------------  -------------  ---------
red       128              40             bitter
blue      30               10             sweet
```

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Is that intentional, or a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this:

```
library(jsonlite)

json = '{
    "useless_info1": "trash1",
    "useless_info2": "trash2",
    "useless_info3": "trash3",
    "usefull_info": [
        {
            "color": "red",
            "sizes": {
                "height": 128,
                "width": 40
            },
            "flavour": "bitter"
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "sizes": {
                "height": 30,
                "width": 10
            },
            "flavour": "sweet"
        }
    ]
}'

fromJSON(json)$usefull_info
#>   color sizes.height sizes.width flavour
#> 1   red          128          40  bitter
#> 2  blue           30          10   sweet
```